# What key does the symbol ⌅ ("projective") refer to?

Tags: keyboard

From https://sequelpro.com/docs/get-started/keyboard-shortcuts:

> Run all queries   <kbd>⌅</kbd> or <kbd>⌘   R</kbd>

What key does the <kbd>⌅</kbd> (["projective"](https://unicode-table.com/en/2305/)) symbol refer to?

I'm using a Mac, but I'm interested to know if it matches different keys on other operating systems as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the  ⌤ key, which represents **Enter**. This is not the same as carriage Return, represented with a ⏎ or ↵ symbol, and also distinct from the similar ⌅ 'Projective' character.
Although most of the time Enter and Return do the same, there is a difference. While the Enter key is meant to sent entered input to the active program or invoke the default function of a GUI element, the Return key is meant to reset the position to the caret to beginning of the line of a text.
On laptop (and some short) keyboards fn+Return triggers it.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_key) says:

> the "Enter" key is commonly labelled with its name in plain text on
>   generic PC keyboards, or with the symbol ⌤ (U+2324 up arrowhead
>   between two horizontal bars) on many Apple Mac keyboards.